# почему не решает уравнение?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(0,"");
    int a,b,c,x;
    int t = x^2;
    double x_1,x_2;
    cout<<"Введите значения :"<<endl;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b; 
    cin >> c;

    cout << "Значение а = " << a <<endl;
    cout << "Значение b = " << b << endl;
    cout << "Значение c = " << c << endl;

    int count = a*t^2 + b*t + c;
    double d = b^2 - 4*a*c;

    if (count >= 0 )
    {
        x_1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / 2 * a;
        x_2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / 2 * a;
        cout<<"Первый корень = "<<x_1<<endl;
        cout<<"Второй корень = "<<x_2<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Корней нет!";
        cout << "А не должно быть равно нулю!";
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как указал @SeniorPomidor, у вас как минимум неинициализированная переменная `x`, значение которой вы пытаетесь возвести в степень в строке `int t = x^2;`.

Comment: У вас по условию коэффициенты уравнения только целые?

Comment: и не забудьте, что x_2 - это на самом деле t^2. поэтому от положительного корня нужно вычислить квадратный корень (если не прошли мнимые числа)

Comment: @Igor ой, наоборот. t=x_^2

Answer (score 1):

```
int t = x^2;
```

Предположим, есть такой оператор "шапочка" :-), который возводит число в степень. Чему равно `t` после этой строчки?

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Уберите из кода все строчки, где встречается переменная `t`. И измените проверку на

```
double d = b*b - 4*a*c;
if (d >= 0)
{
  x_1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
  x_2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
  ...
```

*Update*

Плюс, вычисление корней из `x_1` и `x_2` - как в ответе @SeniorPomidor.

Comment: t не известная переменная,это двойное квадратное уравнение.

Comment: @Sagaydak1411 Однако, Вы используете ее ниже, чтобы вычислить `count`.

Comment: вот по этому я не вижу других путей для решения этой задачи,зайдя в тупик ,обратился на этот сайт за помощью

Answer (score 1):

это биквадратное уравнение. Имеет вид a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c, но мы будем использовать замену. пусть t=x^2.  тогда уравнение имеет вид a*t^2 + b*t + c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0,"");
    int a,b,c,x;
    double x_1,x_2;
    cout<<"Введите значения :"<<endl;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;

    cout << "Значение а = " << a <<endl;
    cout << "Значение b = " << b << endl;
    cout << "Значение c = " << c << endl;

    double d = b^2 - 4*a*c;

    if (count >= 0 )
    {
        x_1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / 2 * a;
        x_2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / 2 * a;
        // так как t может быть только положительным числом из-за t=x^2, 
       //то нужно проверить, что корни не отризательные 
        if(x_1 > 0){
            int root1 = sqrt(x_1);

            cout<<"Первый корень = "<<root1<<endl;
            cout<<"Второй корень = -"<<root1<<endl;
        }
        // и второй корень тоже 
        if(x_2 > 0){
            int root1 = sqrt(x_2);

            cout<<"Третий корень = "<<root1<<endl;
            cout<<"4 корень = -"<<root1<<endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Корней нет!";
        cout << "А не должно быть равно нулю!";
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Уберите из кода все строчки, где встречаются переменные `t` и `count`.

Comment: да, спасибо, что сказал

Answer (score 0):

`^` — это побитовое *исключающее или*. Для возведения в степень используйте `std::pow()` из заголовочного файла `<cmath>`:

```
int t = std::pow(x, 2);
```

Но ещё лучшим решением, раз у вас целые числа, будет замена возведения в квадрат на умножение числа самого на себя:

```
int t = x * x;
```

Это будет быстрее по времени вычисления, а также не приведёт к потере точности при больших числах.

Comment: `int a,b,c,x;     int t = x*x;` чему будет равен t, если х не инициализирован?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, а, вот оно что. А я уже дальше пошёл по ошибкам.

Comment: не инициализированная переменная х,что сделать с ней?

Comment: @Sagaydak1411, не знаю, это ваш алгоритм, и только вам известно, что эта *x* вообще обозначает. По общепринятой системе обозначений могу предположить, что это какой-то корень уравнения. Но как вы можете его использовать, предварительно не вычислив?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, ^^^